# Cannot parse JSON in Ckan API

Tags: ckan

I'm doing a datastore_research with filters in a Ckan API

`https://dados.uffs.edu.br/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=75eb15ab-c30f-4c40-8c19-a5bf936a0aa5&filters={"coordenador":"test"}`

But if I add a ";" character in the value of query param "filter", I will receive an error, like the example below.

Request example: `https://dados.uffs.edu.br/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=75eb15ab-c30f-4c40-8c19-a5bf936a0aa5&filters={"coordenador":"te;st"}`

Response:`{ "help": "https://dados.uffs.edu.br/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_search", "success": false, "error": { "__type": "Validation Error", "filters": [ "Cannot parse JSON" ] } }`

How can I solve this? Cause I need to send ";" in the filter value.

Comment: `https://dados.uffs.edu.br/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=75eb15ab-c30f-4c40-8c19-a5bf936a0aa5&filters={%22coordenador%22:%22te%3Bst%22}`

Comment: Why replace ; to %3B solve the problem?

Comment: If you put certain characters in a URL, you can break the URL (because the characters mean something). The term for preventing characters from being parsed as special characters is 'escaping'. I suggest researching `URL Escape Characters` such as https://docs.microfocus.com/OMi/10.62/Content/OMi/ExtGuide/ExtApps/URL_encoding.htm or https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP etc, etc